# Adding request.user to model field in django rest framework upon form submission

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am working on an app using Django and React and I use DRF to create APIs. I have a form that contains a field called submittedUser that I want it to define the user that posted the form

in models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
class entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    submittedUser = models.ForeignKey('User',blank=True,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='submitteduser')
```

serializers.py:

```
class EntryFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = entry
        fields = ['id','title', 'submittedUser']
```

views.py:

```
class EntryFormViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser]
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        serializer = EntryFormSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(submittedUser = self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want upon posting data, the submittedUser field is the loggedin user (request.user in normal django view) but when I post data it gives me error

```
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
eError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f94a584dd80>": "entry.submittedUser" must be a "User" instance.
```

**Update:**

This is the view of the form page itself

```
def formsPage(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    theUser = request.user
    theUserProfile = userInfo.objects.get(user = theUser.id)
    if theUserProfile.is_admin:
        return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
    else:
        return render(request, "frontend/login.html", {
            "message": " login to continue"
        })
   
else:
    return render(request, "frontend/login.html", {
            "message": "login to continue"
        })

so how can I solve this
```

Comment: Apparently you did not pass the token, or at least the user is not logged in at the time you submit the request.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The form already isn't shown if the user isn't logged In and the View of the page itself returns the login page (I have added the view in the page)

Comment: But the fact that the form shows, is not relevant at all. You only use token authentication, so that means you need to pass a token to the API to get authenticated. Not a session, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually I am new to DRF so how can I solve this?